# HelloWorld vert.x not starting

Tags: javascript, vert.x

I'm trying to get a vert.x HelloWorld project running based on this: https://vertx.io/blog/vert-x3-says-hello-to-npm-users/

I've done npm init and installed vertx3-min 3.8.3. But when i execute "npm start" I get the following error:

vertxdemo@1.0.0 start C:\Users\Tiago Redaelli\Desktop\VertxDemo

> vertx run server.js

```
C:\Users\Tiago Redaelli\Desktop\VertxDemo>#!/bin/sh       
'#!' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Tiago Redaelli\Desktop\VertxDemo>basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
'basedir' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Tiago Redaelli\Desktop\VertxDemo>case `uname` in
'case' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Tiago Redaelli\Desktop\VertxDemo>*CYGWIN* | *MINGW* | *MSYS*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
'*CYGWIN*' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 255
npm ERR! vertxdemo@1.0.0 start: `vertx run server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 255
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vertxdemo@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Tiago Redaelli\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-23T09_18_52_079Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\Tiago Redaelli\Desktop\VertxDemo>
```

The part trying to start server.js taken from the example looks like this:

```
"start": "./node_modules/.bin/vertx run server.js"
```

This is the project directory

**Update**

After installing vertx 3.8 and setting the path to C:\Program Files\vertx\bin I can enter "vertx version" but it still complains over the contents in the shell file as seen previously.

This is the file referenced by the start command:

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*|*MINGW*|*MSYS*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir//bin/bash" ]; then
  "$basedir//bin/bash"  "$basedir/../vertx3-min/vertx/bin/vertx" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  /bin/bash  "$basedir/../vertx3-min/vertx/bin/vertx" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on windows operating system, so your start script should be the bat one:

```
vertx.bat
```

Try replacing the previous commands with that one instead and your application should work.

Comment: ""./node_modules/.bin/vertx.bat run server.js"? --> Cannot find path '$basedir/../vertx3-min/vertx/bin/vertx.bat"   "$@'

Comment: Oh... I know what is happening. You installed it with npm itself on windows, so npm created wrapper scripts which override the original bat files. This is a bug. You should create an issue on GitHub.